# How to create custom web background using repeating icon pattern?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, icon, background

Lately I've been seeing a lot of backgrounds of webpages having a pattern like this:

[image: Example image]

Seems like a trend to have such a background for a webpage. Does anyone know what is this called? If possible, please also simply advise how to go about creating it, thanks a bunch!

Comment: just make those icons in illustrator and import or copy paste and make it a brush a pattern brush and use it

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=background+pattern+collage+tileable&rlz=1C1GIGM_enGB697GB697&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXhuKomPXTAhXDLcAKHUwYCYwQsAQIJg&biw=2560&bih=1334#tbm=isch&q=background+pattern+icons++tileable

Comment: It repeats the elements and shapes, so I think it's a rapport pattern or tileable background

Answer (score 1):

It's just a tileable (or repeatable) background, made from simple line art. It has no special name.

This is really a very broad question, so I can only give a very broad answer.

If you are asking how to draw simple shapes in Photoshop, have you tried using the Pen tool or the Shape tools to make simple graphics?  You can apply a simple stroke to a shape in Photoshop.  If you don't know how, there are tutorials online that show you how to use the Pen tool in Photoshop.

Photoshop is not really the ideal software for this kind of thing, but it would do at a push. It would be easier to use vector image editing software such as Adobe Illustrator or even the free software Inkscape(dot)org.